# How to convert Markdown to PDF without writing an intermediate HTML file?

Tags: markdown, wkhtmltopdf

The goal is to take a Markdown file and output a PDF. Using the CLI tools from [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) and [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), I have:

```
marked file.md -o file.html && wkhtmltopdf git.html file.pdf && start file.pdf
```

This works but it leaves a useless HTML file to clean up. I would like to avoid this read/write step altogether. Is there a way to pipe the output from `marked` to `wkhtmltopdf` directly?

Is there a better tool to use? I'm open to JavaScript, C#, and command-line based tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marked` outputs to standard out by default, and `wkhtmltopdf` can read from `stdin` if you specify `-` as the file to read, so you can pipe one into the other:

```
marked file.md | wkhtmltopdf - file.pdf
```